# Ошибка передачи QFile, как аргумента

Tags: c++, qt

Есть QFile, который нужно передать в функцию. При попытке сделать это выходит ошибка `call to deleted constructor of QFile`. Код выглядит так:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  const QFile f("C:/Folder/file.txt");
  processFile(f);
}

void processFile(QFile file) {
  if((file.exists()) && (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))) {
      while(!file.atEnd()) {
          // do something
      }
  }
}
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Можно по ссылке, но не легче ли передать саму строку, а уже в processFile создать QFile?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, если передаю QString, а в функции создаю файл, появляется ошибка "copying parameter of type 'QFile' invokes deleted constructor"

Comment: Разобрался с этим. В объявлении функции забыл изменить тип аргумента на QString, который поменял в реализации